# Prepending part of a filename to a .csv file using bash/sed

Tags: bash, csv, sed

I have a couple of files in a directory that are named like this;

```
1_38OE983729JKHKJV.csv
```

an integer followed by an ID (the Integer and ID are both unique).

I need to prepend this ID to every line of the file for each file in the folder to prepare the files for import to a database (and discard the integer part of the filename). The contents of the file look something like this:

```
BW;20015;11,45;0,49;41;174856;4103399
BA;25340;11,41;0,55;40;222161;4599779
BB;800;7,58;0,33;42;10559;239887
HE;6301;9,11;0,39;40;69191;1614302
.
.
.
Total;112613;9,33;0,43;40;1207387;25897426
```

The end result should look something like this:

```
38OE983729JKHKJV;BW;20015;11,45;0,49;41;174856;4103399
38OE983729JKHKJV;BA;25340;11,41;0,55;40;222161;4599779
38OE983729JKHKJV;BB;800;7,58;0,33;42;10559;239887
38OE983729JKHKJV;HE;6301;9,11;0,39;40;69191;1614302
.
.
.
38OE983729JKHKJV;Total;112613;9,33;0,43;40;1207387;25897426
```

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Spelling and vocabular for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following too in single awk and which will take care of the number of files which are getting opened during this operation too, so that we will avoid the error of maximum number of files opened.

```
awk 'FNR==1{close(val);val=FILENAME;split(FILENAME,a,"_");sub(/\..*/,"",a[2])} {print a[2]","$0}' *.csv
```

Comment: How do I have to execute this? Does this have to be in the same directory?

Comment: @Tassanara: try to run on terminal, it will simply print the lines, if you need output into a single output file then you could do > output_file at last of command, let me know how it goes then.

Comment: @Tassanara: glad that it helped you.

Comment: That won't work for multiple files. For example `close(val)` is trying to close the previous `FILENAME` value, but `close()` only works on files opened as a result of redirection (e.g. `print > file` or `getline < file`), not as part of the regular work loop. Just printing to stdout can obviously only work 1 file at a time anyway though so don't try `*.csv`. If you're going to use split() on FILENAME, why not split it at both `_` and `.` instead of splitting it at `_` and then sub() at `.`? The 3rd arg for split() is a regexp btw not a string. Finally, the desired separator is `;`, not `,`;.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the files with `for`, use parameter expansion to extract the id.

```
#!/bin/bash
for csv in *.csv ; do
    prefix=${csv%_*}
    id=${csv#*_}
    id=${id%.csv}
    sed -i~ "s/^/$id;/" "$csv"
done
```

If the ID can contain underscores, you might need to be more careful with the expansion.

Comment: it gives me this error:
My input: sh addId.sh

    :command not found
    'ddId.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `do
    'ddId.sh: line 3: `for csv in *.csv ; do

Comment: Don't use `sh` to call `bash` scripts.

Comment: My bad, thanks! I'm used to using macOS, where sh actually calls bash instead of the standard bourne shell. Live and learn!

Answer (score 1):

With ***awk*** tool:

```
for f in *csv; do awk '{ fn=FILENAME; $0=substr(fn,index(fn,"_")+1,length(fn)-6)";"$0 }1' "$f" > tmp && mv tmp "$f"; done
```

- `fn=FILENAME` - the filename

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for inplace editing and gensub() all you need is:

```
awk -i inplace '{print gensub(/.*_(.*)\..*/,"\\1;",1,FILENAME) $0}' *.csv
```

No shell loops or anything else necessary, just that command.